# Section Title indents too much at the start of a new page

Tags: sectioning, indentation, sections-paragraphs

I have an issue where my consecutive sections when added are being alternatively indented in or out.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, titlepage]{article}

\title{Bla \\
Bla\\
Bla
}
\author{Bla  \and
    Bla
    }

\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents % create a table of contens 

\newpage

\section{Introduction}
Make it possible for all to write documents with \LaTeX{}!

\paragraph{Outline}
First we start with a little example of the article class, which is an 
important documentclass. But there would be other documentclasses like 
book \ref{book}, report \ref{report} and letter \ref{letter} which are 
described in Section \ref{documentclasses}. Finally, Section 
\ref{conclusions} gives the conclusions.


\subsection{Project}
Go more in detail \ldots

\subsection{Group}
Below are the key team members within the project.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla
\item Bla 
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\end{description}

\section{Project Evaluation} \label{projecteval}

\begin{itemize}
\item article
\item book 
\item report 
\item letter 
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Project Management and Process} \label{projectprocess}

\paragraph{Effectiveness} \label{effectiveness}
dfads
\subsection{Requirements Modelling and UML} \label{uml}

\section{Group Member Evaluation} \label{groupeval}

\subsection{Bla} \label{Bla}

\subsubsection{Role Classification}


\subsubsection{Strengths}


\subsubsection{Weaknesses}


\subsubsection{Recommendations}


\section{Score Summary}

Here are the summary scores of each individual in the team from my perspective:


\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|p{2cm}|}
\hline
Team Member & Contribution Amount & Contribution Quality & Total \\
\hline 
l stand for left & 
c for center &
r for right & 
and p for predefined size \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 


\section{What I would have done differently}


\section{Reflections}


\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}


\end{document}
```

`\section{Project Evaluation}` appears at the start of page 2, and `\section{Introduction}` appears at the start of page 1. The first section, Introduction, appears with the correct indentation, but then every section and subsection and paragraph below Project Evaluation is appearing highly indented.

And yes, I used a template - very new to `LaTeX`!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you mean the 'indentation' of the 2nd page with sections. This is the switch from even to odd side etc. Replace `twoside` by `oneside` in the `\documentclass[....]{article}` option list and report, if this is what you want

Comment: note that `\paragraph` is a 4th level heading it should be used in the sequence `\section,\subsection,\subsubsection,\paragraph`

Comment: Thanks both! @ChristianHupfer this `oneside` seems to have solved the issue, and I can still have the paragraph style section appearing ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question could be solved by switching from `twoside` to `oneside` option, which shifts the 'indentation' -- i.e. the margins, such that recto and verso pages look alike according to the horizontal margins

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage]{article}

\title{
Theory on Brontosaurs
%Bla \\
%Bla\\
%Bla
}
\author{Miss Ann Elk  \and
    Arthur Gumby (Brain Surgeon)
    }

\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents % create a table of contens 

\newpage

\section{Introduction}
Make it possible for all to write documents with \LaTeX{}!

%\paragraph{Outline}
%First we start with a little example of the article class, which is an 
%important documentclass. But there would be other documentclasses like 
%book \ref{book}, report \ref{report} and letter \ref{letter} which are 
%described in Section \ref{documentclasses}. Finally, Section 
%\ref{conclusions} gives the conclusions.


\subsection{Project}
Go more in detail \ldots

\subsection{Group}
Below are the key team members within the project.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla
\item Bla 
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\item[Bla]{is described in Section \ref{Bla}}
\end{description}

\section{Project Evaluation} \label{projecteval}

\begin{itemize}
\item article
\item book 
\item report 
\item letter 
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Project Management and Process} \label{projectprocess}

\paragraph{Effectiveness} \label{effectiveness}
dfads
\subsection{Requirements Modelling and UML} \label{uml}

\section{Group Member Evaluation} \label{groupeval}

\subsection{Bla} \label{Bla}

\subsubsection{Role Classification}


\subsubsection{Strengths}


\subsubsection{Weaknesses}


\subsubsection{Recommendations}


\section{Score Summary}

Here are the summary scores of each individual in the team from my perspective:


\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|p{2cm}|}
\hline
Team Member & Contribution Amount & Contribution Quality & Total \\
\hline 
l stand for left & 
c for center &
r for right & 
and p for predefined size \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 


\section{What I would have done differently}


\section{Reflections}


\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}


\end{document}
```